# melt data.frame in r and store unused columns in a column (separated by commata)

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2, dcast

## old problem, for new one see below

I have a data.frame

```
df<-data.frame("name"  = c("A","A","B","C"), 
               "class" = c("ab","cd","cd","ef"),
               "type"  = c("alpha","beta","gamma","delta"))

> df
  name class  type
1    A    ab alpha
3    A    ab  beta
4    B    cd gamma
5    C    ef delta
```

so name `A` has both type `alpha` and `beta` and appears both with

I want my data frame to look like this (`type` column may contain one long string separated by comma):

```
> df
  name class  type
1    A    ab alpha, beta
2    B    cd gamma
3    C    ef delta
```

what did not work was
`dcast(df, name~type)`

any suggestions?

## New Problem

I want `name` to be the decisive selector. So A has class `ab` with type `alpha` and class `cd` with types `alpha` and `beta`.

```
df<-data.frame("name"  = c("A","A","A","B","C"), 
               "class" = c("ab","cd","cd","cd","ef"),
               "type"  = c("alpha","alpha","beta","gamma","delta"))

> df
  name class  type
1    A    ab alpha
2    A    cd alpha
3    A    cd  beta
4    B    cd gamma
5    C    ef delta
```

dplyr::summarise(var = paste(type, collapse = ", "))` (see solution below) returns

```
> df
  name var
1    A alpha, alpha, beta
2    B gamma
3    C delta
```

This causes a double `alpha` in the first row. I am looking for a possibilty to remove this doublet. Target:

```
> df
  name var
1    A alpha, beta
2    B gamma
3    C delta
```

## edit:

solved by Gregor, see comments

Comment: `melt` and `dcast` are used when you (melt) need to convert multiple columns to two columns (key column and value column), or (dcast) when you need to convert two key/value columns into multiple columns. Here, you are keeping the same columns so you're not using `melt` or `dcast`.

Comment: Regarding your new problem, you can use the existing answer just change `paste(type, ...)` to `paste(unique(type), ...)`. In general, it's bad form to edit a question and change the requirements after getting a satisfactory answer to the original question. It's usually better to just open a new question.

Comment: your solutions works very well @Gregor, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try this. We group by name and class, then collapse with a comma:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(name, class) %>%
  summarise(type = paste(type, collapse = ","))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   name [?]
#>   name  class type      
#>   <fct> <fct> <chr>     
#> 1 A     ab    alpha,beta
#> 2 B     cd    gamma     
#> 3 C     ef    delta
```

Created on 2018-09-25 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: `...collapse = ", "`) and I am happy.